# How can i change "Curso" class to print in other class?

Tags: java, oracle, arraylist

I got 2 classes

```
class Curso{
    private String name;

    public Curso(String nome){
       this.name = nome;
    }

    public String getName(){
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class testaCurso{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Course c1 = new Course("Computer Science");

        c1.addDisciplina("AlgProgII");
        c1.addDisciplina("SO");
        c1.addDisciplina ("Grafos");
        System.out.println(c1);
    }
}
```

i gotta modify the Course class so that it can store the names of the Disciplina that make up the course and work for the test above with the output as shown. Consider that a course will not have a maximum of 50 subjects.

output:

Course: Computer Science,
Disciplinas:{ AlgProgII SO Grafos }

Comment: i forgot writing (String name) in   public Curso(String ){
       this.name = nome;
    }

Comment: Do you keep a list in Course class?

Comment: @PedroCarmona: Note that you can click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67951243/edit) link below your post to do corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
class Curso {
    private String name;

    // Add an list field containg the disciplinas
    private final List<String> disciplinas = new ArrayList<>();

    public Curso(String name){
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
       return this.name;
    }

    // Add a `addDisciplina` method
    public void addDisciplina(String name) {
        disciplinas.add(name);
    }

    // Override the `toString` method
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course: " + name + ", Disciplinas: + ", disciplinas;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can implement `toString()` like the following:

```
public class Course {
    private final String name;
    private final List<String> disciplinas;

    public Course(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.disciplinas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Course(String name, List<String> disciplinas){
        this.name = name;
        this.disciplinas = new ArrayList<>(disciplinas);
    }

    public void addDisciplinas(String discplina){
        this.disciplinas.add(discplina);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course: " + name  + ", Disciplinas: {" + disciplinas.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")) +"}";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Course course = new Course("Computer Science", Arrays.asList("AlgProgII", "SO", "Grafos"));
System.out.println(course);
```

Output:

```
Course: Computer Science, Disciplinas: {AlgProgII SO Grafos}
```